# problems of training RCF model using caffe

Tags: caffe

I'm using caffe to train a model. I am sure I have connected the data layer with the train.txt in the source of image_data_param.But when I try ./train.sh. It always prompt: can not find image.

Ubuntu 18.04 openCV3 python2

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageLabelmapData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    mean_value: 104.00699
    mean_value: 116.66877
    mean_value: 122.67892
  }
  image_data_param {
    root_folder: "/home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train/"
    source: "/home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train.txt"
    batch_size: 1
    shuffle: true
    new_height:0
    new_width: 0
  }
}

I0828 19:29:13.834946 14079 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer data
I0828 19:29:13.835011 14079 net.cpp:101] Creating Layer data
I0828 19:29:13.835031 14079 net.cpp:409] data -> data
I0828 19:29:13.835059 14079 net.cpp:409] data -> label
I0828 19:29:13.835124 14079 image_labelmap_data_layer.cpp:42] Opening file /home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train.txt
I0828 19:29:13.835505 14079 image_labelmap_data_layer.cpp:52] Shuffling data
I0828 19:29:13.835677 14079 image_labelmap_data_layer.cpp:57] A total of 242 images.
E0828 19:29:13.836748 14079 io.cpp:80] Could not open or find file /home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train//home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train/satellite144.jpg
E0828 19:29:13.836797 14079 io.cpp:80] Could not open or find file /home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train//home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train/400.jpg
F0828 19:29:13.836818 14079 image_labelmap_data_layer.cpp:86] Check failed: cv_img.data Could not load /home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train/satellite144.jpg
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
./train.sh: line 8: 14079 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./solve.py
```

Answer (score 0):

i think image path is wrong
check your image path

Comment: Thanks, but I think my path is correct,because 242 images can be read, although I have 484 images.

Comment: Could not open or find file /home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train//home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train/satellite144.jpg  I think this is a overlap "/home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train/"

You should delete this sentence "/home/yogang/Desktop/rawdata/train/" in the train.txt file